# How to grab a react element in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

If a website uses react, how can i grab an element by class?

For example here is a div:

```
<div class="Blockreact__Block-sc-1xf18x6-0 Flexreact__Flex-sc-1twd32i-0 IgxsY jYqxGr"></div>
```

How can i grab this div with javascript everytime, if the website gets built again?
If im correct the react classes are always different after every build, or will it stay the same always?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the classes assigned to the element you want are unpredictable then you need to change your approach to finding the element.

For example, you might look for an element which is the third next sibling of the first `h1` in the document.

The specifics depend on the precise nature of the DOM you are dealing with.

Comment: Thats what i was thinking also, but isn't there really a simplier way to do this? What if they decide to put on more child into the parent element? Then the div can go from third to fourth position.

Comment: Then you'll have to adjust. Web scraping is hard and unreliable. Websites are rarely designed with the intention that third party code (other than standard browsers operating in a standard way) should interact with them. When they are, they generally use RESTful APIs to achieve that.